# What type is this aircraft and engine at Munich airport?

Tags: jet-engine, airliner, aircraft-identification, airbus-a350

[image: Munich airport]

Please help me to identify the plane and engine.

Comment: Lufthansa Airbus A350-941, 2x RR Trent XWB?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fact that it is a single deck, twin engined aircraft with that distinctive wingtip confirm that it is an Airbus A350, operated by Lufthansa. The -900 series is the only A350 in service at this time, and Lufthansa has not ordered the -1000 series.

The A350 is powered by [Rolls Royce Trent XWB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_XWB) engines.

Comment: absolutely! Airbus A350-941 D-AIXC

Comment: @user27467 How can you tell it is (D-AIX) **C**?

Comment: because I know date and time of photo, and there are few A350 in LH fleet

Comment: Nice plane! I was lucky to fly it twice last week (BOS <-> MUC)